# Quickly accessing file names listed by the ls command on Linux shell

Tags: linux, ls

I am working on the Linux shell, and I usually have to deal with files that have complicated names. For example, I list the files of the current directory using `ls`:

```
MOD11A1.A2012193.h12v03.005.2012196013543.hdf
MOD11A1.A2012193.h12v04.005.2012196013541.hdf
MOD11A1.A2012193.h12v05.005.2012196013541.hdf
```

And then, if I need to open one of them, I would write:

```
vim MOD11A1.A2012193.h12v03.005.2012196013543.hdf
```

The way I do it, is by first selecting the file name from the list provided by `ls`, right click, copy it, right click, paste it after `vim`. 
Is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wildcard expansion, i.e. for the second file:

`vim *v04*41*`

or, if your shell supports it, tab-completion:

type `vim M`; press [Tab], that completes all up to next difference, i.e. `OD11A1.A2012193.h12v0`; type `4`; press [Tab], and so on.

Comment: `zsh` *does* have many amazing features, but if it's just about tab-completion, you can have this in `bash` as well these days :) .

Answer (score 1):

If you would like open first of `hdf` files then use:

```
vim `ls -1 *.hdf | head -n 1`
```

`ls-1` - minifies dump to just a name per row

`head -n 1` - selects first item only